# Passing through variable into partial and using an #is helper - Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I'm trying to pass a variable (tag name) into a Handlebars partial and use an #is block helper on the tag but for some reason it just won't play ball. This is my code:

Call to my partial and passing through the tag name.

```
{{> nav tagged='page' }}
```

In the partial itself I do the following (tagged is the variable name passed through):

```
{{#each tags}}
  {{#is tag tagged}}
    {{#each pages}}
       // Do code here
    {{/each}}
  {{/is}}
{{/each}}
```

If I just render the tagged variable it displays the variable value as expected so a bit confused as to why its not working.

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear to me where this "is statement" comes from. Is this a Handlebars helper that you have created? Additionally, it will be easier to help you if you provide some sample data.

Comment: `#is` comes from handlebars-helpers.js. SO doesn't have a tag for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that the `tagged` variable is in the parent context but you're trying to reference it within the `#each tags` loop.

You can reference the parent context with `../` so the working code would be

```
{{#each tags}}
  {{#is tag ../tagged}}
    {{#each pages}}
       // Do code here
    {{/each}}
  {{/is}}
{{/each}}
```